# how can i do this with reduce? I'm trying without success

Tags: javascript, reduce

```
 songsList(i) {
    const valueSongs = [];
    for (let index = 1; index < i.length; index++) {
      valueSongs.push(i[index]);
    }
    return valueSongs;
  }
```

I'm just practicing but stagnant so far

Comment: I would firstly suggest using meaningful variable names and `i` tends to get used as a short name for `index` in for loops. You seem to be doing a shallow copy of `i` and, as such, `reduce` is entirely inappropriate. Maybe you meant to use `map` instead?

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect from the method `reduce`.
By the provided context, it seems you are trying to remove the first value of the array(index 0). Right?
If then, you don't have to use reduce.

BTW, with reduce, the answer would be like the below.

```js
function songsList(i) {
  return i.reduce((acc,val, index) => {
    if(index) 
      acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(songsList[1,2,3,4,5]) // [2,3,4,5]
```